# Blocking method calls on an object for a period of time

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, sleep

I'm working on a multithreaded Java project where I would like to have objects that prevent their methods from being called from any thread for some period of time. Ideally, those method calls would not be thrown out, but simply queued up until the cooldown from the previous method has completed. Here's a simple example of a class with that kind of functionality:

```
public class A {

    private synchronized void cooldown(long ms) {
        long finishTime = ms + System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < finishTime);
    }

    public synchronized void foo() {
        // foo's code
        cooldown(1000);
    }

    public synchronized void bar() {
        // bar's code
        cooldown(2000);
    }

}
```

This works, but I'm expecting to have quite a few of the above objects and I feel like the loop inside of `cooldown()` is wasteful. I'd love to use a construct like `Thread.sleep()`, but in this case, that would have the undesirable effects of forcing the calling thread to sleep and not preventing any other thread from making method calls on `A`. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

To clarify, given the following implementation:

```
public synchronized void foo() {
    System.out.println("foo");
    cooldown(1000);
}

public synchronized void bar() {
    System.out.println("bar");
    cooldown(2000);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final A a = new A();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            a.foo();
        }
    }).start();

    System.out.println("foobar");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            a.bar();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I would like **foo** and **foobar** to print instantly (order doesn't matter), followed by **bar** a second later. If `cooldown()` just called `Thread.currentThread().sleep(ms)` instead of the current implementation, then **foo** would print instantly, followed by **foobar** and **bar** a second later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd love to use a construct like Thread.sleep(), but in this case, that would have the undesirable effects of forcing the calling thread to sleep and not preventing any other thread from making method calls on A. Any suggestions?

I don't see the difference between calling `Thread.sleep()` versus your spin loop aside from the fact that the spin loop wastes CPU.  If you are inside `cooldown(...)` then that instance of `A` is `synchronized`.

If you mean that you have other methods that are `synchronized` and you don't want the thread that is cooling down to be holding the lock then you can use `this.wait(...)` which will release the lock during the sleep.  Of course is someone is calling `notify(...)` this won't work.

```
private synchronized void cooldown(long ms) {
    try {
       long waitUntilMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + ms;
       long waitTimeMillis = ms;
       do {
          this.wait(waitTimeMillis);
          // we need this dance/loop because of spurious wakeups, thanks @loki
          waitTimeMillis = waitUntilMillis - System.currentTimeMillis();
       } while (waitTimeMillis > 0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

The right thing to do is to *not* have `synchronized` methods and only synchronize when you specifically need to.  Then you can cooldown easily without holding a lock.

```
private void cooldown(long ms) {
    try {
       this.sleep(ms);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
    }
}
public void foo() { 
    synchronized (this) {
       // foo's code
    }
    cooldown(1000);
}
```

Comment: Spin lock is needed, spin loop is a big mistake and will take away all CPU usage.

Comment: You must use spin lock in your code, if your thread is interrupted thread will come out of wait before time has passed.

Comment: What's the problem if the thread is interrupted?  If it is interrupted chances are you _want_ to come out of the loop.  Otherwise you are just ignoring the interrupt @loki.

Comment: Thread can be interruped due to various reasons, somwtimes which are not in your control. Its always advised to use spin lock when using wait.

Comment: That's completely wrong @loki.  How else can a thread be interrupted "not in your control"?  Please provide references.

Comment: Let me search but just read about spin lock. You will always find wait in a spin lock.

Comment: Ahhh.  I see.  You are talking about spurious signals.  True.  Nothing to do with interrupt though @loki.

Comment: Yes, i was talking about spurious signals and i have always seen wait in while loop only. Do you mean to say its not necessary and should be avoided?

Comment: No, you are correct.  Wait loops should be in a loop although it's more important when using wait/notify.  Here it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: Hopefully the example in my last edit is helpful, it seems to me that `Thread.sleep()` would print `foo` followed by `foobar` and `bar` a second later instead of allowing `foobar` to be printed instantly.

Comment: Either of my answers will work @wheels but the 2nd part is the way to go.  The first is a hack.

Comment: I'm not sure if `cooldown()` can get away without holding a lock, your second approach prints everything at once. Adding synchronized works great though!

Comment: Ah, you can avoid synchronizing `cooldown()` if the calls to cooldown are in `synchronized` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You have following options:

1. Thread.sleep() should work fine if called inside synchronized method. All other threads would be prevented and your thread will hold lock and wait.
2. Use timed wait/notify in a synchronized block. That should also do the job.

EDIT:

See the below code

public class A {

```
final volatile Object lck = new Object();
volatile boolean waitStatus = true;

private void cooldown(long ms) {        

    synchronized(lck){
       long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

       //Do thread need to wait
       if(waitStatus){
         while(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime < ms) 
          lck.wait(gapTime);

        //Wait over no other thread will wait           
        waitStatus = false;  
       }    


    }
}

public  void foo() {
    // foo's code
    cooldown(1000);
}

public void bar() {
    // bar's code
    cooldown(2000);
}
```

}

Comment: After changing `cooldown()` to call `Thread.currentThread().sleep(ms)`, method calls from other threads are blocked, but the calling thread is forced to sleep (which I was hoping to avoid). Did I interpret your advice correctly, or is there a more clever way of doing things that I missed?

Comment: My understanding is that you want call to method blocked from all threads for certain duration in which case sending thread to sleep or wait is right approach. Do you want something different?

Comment: This looks like it will only wait once.  Is that the intention?

Comment: Also, you need to be careful of the gapTime calculations (not shown) because the delay can't be negative.

Comment: Yes, in my code i gave flexibility of waiting only once. Also "System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime" will always be positive as current time will always be greater than start time.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close already ... minor change ...

```
private synchronized void cooldown(long ms) throws InterruptedException {
    Thead.sleep(ms);
}
```

Alternatively, you could handle the `InterruptedException` in the cooldown method itself.

Also, note that your code could actually execute `foo`, `bar`, and `foobar` in any order. The cooldown will slow down the `foo` or the `bar` (depending on which gets executed first).

> I'd love to use a construct like Thread.sleep(), but in this case,
>   that would have the undesirable effects of forcing the calling thread
>   to sleep and not preventing any other thread from making method calls
>   on A.

Your approach does what you want. Other threads ARE prevented from making method calls on A (if you have synchronized the methods - which you have).